# I'm getting a NaN error

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm getting a NaN error in this calculator script: 
Any ideas?

Here is the whole html in a text format:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3u429bn5bjd4i9/orecalculator.txt

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var IDs = [22,17425,17426,1223,17428,17429,1225,17432,17433,1232,17436,17437,1229,17865,17866,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1226,17448,17449,20,17452,17453,11396,17869,17870,1227,17867,17868,18,17455,17456,1224,17459,17460,1228,17463,17464,19,17466,17467,1230,17470,17471];

function calculate(i){
    while (i + 1 < IDs.length) {
        var y=document.getElementById('reward');
        var x=document.getElementById(IDs[i]);
        y.value=parseInt(y.value)+parseInt(x.value);
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? At least one of those elements doesn't have a value that can be parsed.

Comment: y or x could have a value undefined, or a value you aren't expecting.

Comment: How and where do you call `calculate`? Especially: What do you pass?

Comment: Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3u429bn5bjd4i9/orecalculator.txt

Comment: What does this `+1` do in the loop condition? Are you not iterating the last element on purpose?

Comment: The first time `calculate` is run, does Reward have a value? I can see that you're keeping track of the total, but it doesn't start at 0 from what I see, it has an empty value.

Comment: You're getting it because most of the `input`s with ID-s are probably empty. Calling `parseInt()` on an empty string returns a `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Run this code in console and found following output

```
document.getElementById('reward')
//output <input type=​"text" id=​"reward">​
document.getElementById('reward').value
//""
parseInt(document.getElementById('reward').value)
//NaN
parseInt("")
//NaN
```

**Explanation**

parseInt of empty string is `NaN`

**Solution**

Use

```
Reward: <input type="text" id="reward" value="0">
```

instead

```
Reward: <input type="text" id="reward">
```

Fixed: JS Code

```
function calculate(i){
    while (i + 1 < IDs.length) {
        var y=document.getElementById('reward');
        var x=document.getElementById(IDs[i]);
        y.value=parseInt(y.value|0)+parseInt(x.value|0);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth putting failsafes into the JS.

Comment: @Bergi, @-0_0 - Sorry I didn;t get you?

Comment: What can be done in the JavaScript code to prevent this error? E.g. when the user empties one of the inputs, the JS should still work. Can you suggest an update of the script maybe?

Comment: Now the `parseInt` is quite superfluous…

Answer (score 0):

untested but should be something like this:

```
calculate = function (i){

    var y = document.getElementById('reward');
    var x = 0;  
    while (i + 1 < IDs.length) {

        var elm = document.getElementById(IDs[i]);
        x+=parseInt(elm.value||0);
        i++;
    }
    y.value = x;
};
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/8ADQX/

Comment: fixed and added a working fiddle. It is a bit better performance wise as you dont have to scan the document for the reward element every id. Also it defines calculate as a global variable so the input can access it.

Comment: There are no explanations in the fiddle either :-(

Comment: Please explain what the problem was

Comment: I'm still of the opinion that OP was trying to dynamically sum to y.value, but the first time it is run, `reward` is value. Therefore, y.value is undefined, `parseInt(y.value)` is NaN. This just bypasses using y.value till the end. Adding in a default value in the JS or in the HTML would work as well. More specifically: this doesn't "get" form y.value, it only "sets," and it sums within a temp variable and assigns at the end instead of continuously assigning to y.value.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Actually an empty input's `.value` is the empty string `""`, not `undefined`. Which, when you call `parseInt` on, also yields `NaN`

Comment: yup. As state elsewhere it is due to the fact that parseInt(y.value) returns NaN when y.value == "". If the OP wishes to add to the total each time the calculate button is pressed instead of simply summing all the values present, then they can replace y.value with y.value||0 in their original function.